# Let X be a topological space such that A $ \in $ X and A' $ \subset $ P(X) and A' $\neq$ $\emptyset$. Prove or disprove the statements below.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let X be a topological space such that A $ \subset $ X and A' $ \subset $ P(X). Prove or disprove the statements below.

int($\bigcup_{A \in A' }$ A)   $\supset$  $\bigcup_{A \in A'}$int(A)

int($\bigcap_{A \in A'}$A)    = $\bigcap_{A \in A'}$int(A)

$\overline {\bigcup_{A \in A' }A}$   =  $\bigcup_{A \in A'} \bar A$

$\overline {\bigcap_{A \in A' }A}$  $\subset$   $\bigcap_{A \in A'} \bar A$

====================================================================

As we know that the following statements are true, then all of the above statements are also true? Right?

int(A $\cup$ B) $\supset$ int(A) $\cup$ int(B)

int(A $\cap$ B) = int(A) $\cap$ int(B)

$\overline{A \cup B}$ = $\bar A$ $\cup$ $\bar B$

$\overline{A \cap B}$ $\subset$ $\bar A$ $\cap$ $\bar B$

Comment: No. Not a priori. You only know it for the case where $A'$ is finite. Even with induction, you could not even hope to extend the statements to the case where $A'$ is countable. I.e. you either have to look at the proofs of the finite statements and consider whether they actually rely on the finitiness of the involved index sets at all and, if the answer is yes, you need to come up with a new proof.

Comment: My edit: I'm sure you meant $A\subset X$ in the 1st line, not $A\in X$, so I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd one is wrong because it implies that the union of a collection of closed sets is closed. Suppose every $A\in A'$ is closed. Let $B=\cup_{A\in A'}A.$ Since $\bar A=A$ for every $A\in A',$ we have $\cup_{A\in A'}\bar A=\cup_{A\in A'}A=B$ on the RHS, but the LHS is $\bar B.$

Example. Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Let $B$ be $any$ subset of $\Bbb R.$ Let $A'=\{\,\{r\}: r\in B\}.$

Inferences about finite collections rarely apply to infinite collections.

Comment: It is often more convenient to write $\cup A'$ for $\cup_{A\in A'}A.$ They are, by definition, the same thing.

Comment: Well, the second item is wrong by the very same reasoning. ´

Comment: @WoolierThanThou . Yes.............................